# What does this Vagrant error mean and how do you fix it? For 'public_network' and 'private_network' together

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox

I have this in my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

It's giving me this error when I try `vagrant up`

> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>   A host only network interface you're attempting to configure via DHCP
>   already has a conflicting host only adapter with DHCP enabled. The
>   DHCP on this adapter is incompatible with the DHCP settings. Two
>   host only network interfaces are not allowed to overlap, and each
>   host only network interface can have only one DHCP server. Please
>   reconfigure your host only network or remove the virtual machine
>   using the other host only network.

It uses a lot of words, but I still don't understand it. All of my virtual machines are powered off. Why can't there be more than one DHCP client on the network anyways? There are often multiple DHCP clients on the same network! All of my machines are using NAT adapters except for one using Bridged Adapter.

VirtualBox 5.2.4
Vagrant 2.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vagrant a public network is like a private one(in a pure networking sense) with dhcp that is implicitly bridged to your host so it can be accessed from outside your machine, it is a bit ambiguous as the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html) state.

So you are trying to create two networks using DHCP on the same hypervisor for the same machine, this cannot work with Virtualbox as Virtualbox can only assign one IP to one machine over DHCP.

If you don't need "the outside world" to access your machine the public network is useless, just use a private network over DHCP.

Or try using a public network with a private one with a static IP.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a router, and want to create two networks, a public one that the internet can access (WAN), with my physical router as the uplink, and a local network (LAN). Are you saying that a 'public_network' (bridged) automatically uses DHCP even though it's not specified? Now that I think about it, a router would not be a DHCP client on the LAN side. I took your last line and used `config.vm.network "public_network"; config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.1"`.

Comment: That worked, but still generated an extra NAT network? `default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
   default: Adapter 3: hostonly`.

Comment: I think most interpreter use a dedicated network for internal usage, at least that is what kvm/libvirt does(I'm not that familiar with virtualbox details). It allow the hypervisor to control the machine even before the user's network(s) has been set. So you'll probably see 3 interfaces(without loopback) if you run an `ip a` command on the gest. But don't worry too much about that as long as you have your necessary networks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
 config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", netmask: "255.255.0.0", name: "vboxnet3", dhcp_ip:"10.101.0.2", dhcp_lower: "10.101.4.3", :dhcp_upper=>"10.101.4.254"
```

Add this:

```
 config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", netmask: "255.255.0.0", dhcp_ip:"10.101.0.2", dhcp_lower: "10.101.4.3", :dhcp_upper=>"10.101.4.254"
```

For the **netmask, dhcp_ip, etc fields**. Go to VirtualBox > Tools and look for your Host-only Networks.

[image]

Click on the **DCHP Server** tag.
There you will find the fields to map:

- Server Address -> dhcp_ip
- Server Mask -> netmask
- lower and upper are pretty evident

Comment: This works like charm

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and in my case I did the following: 
1) Enabled a new 'host-only' adapter in virtualbox: just select your box, click 'settings', click 'network' and enable a different adapter than your other boxes have.

2) Check the ip of that adapter you created by running 'ipconfig' in powershell or command line in Windows.

3) Finally, in your vagrant configuration file, specify an ip within the adapter's network: config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "place_ip_here".

If your adapter's ipv4 is '172.28.128.1', for example, and subnet mask '255.255.255.0', then your first three numbers in the IP remain the same '172.28.128.another_number_here'

Answer (score 0):

This issue may happens for different reasons. In my case when vagrant boots the vm, it brings up a other network adapter vboxnet2 while I have already created and attached an adapter vboxnet1. Thus, those two adapters were overlapping.
This thread [enter link description here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8878) helped me to solve my issue